# How can I sum rows of a column based on an index condition to create a % of group column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, pandas-groupby

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
# Create DataFrame
import pandas as pd
data = {'Menu Category': ['Appetizers', 'Appetizers', 'Appetizers', 'Mains', 'Mains', 
        'Mains', 'Desserts', 'Desserts', 'Desserts'], 
        'Menu Item': ['Fries', 'Poppers', 'Wings', 'Pasta', 'Burger', 'Pizza', 
                      'Ice Cream', 'Cake', 'Fruit'],
        'Sales Quantity': [100, 50, 40, 200, 400, 250, 100, 120, 50],
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

I would like to add two columns. 1) that shows the % Quantity of the Menu that each item represents (entire menu being this dataset), and 2) that shows the % Quantity of the Menu Category the item belongs to (like what percentage of the `Sale Quantity` does `Fries` represent of the `Appetizers` group, i.e. `(100/190) * 100`).

I know how to get the first column mentioned:

```
# Add % Quantity of Menu Column
percent_menu_qty = []
for i in df['Sales Quantity']:
    i = round(i/df['Sales Quantity'].sum() * 100, 2)
    percent_menu_qty.append(i)
df['% Quantity of Menu'] = percent_menu_qty
df
```

[image]

What I am not sure how to do is the second one. I have tried by setting `Menu Category` as the index and doing the following:

```
# Add % Quantity of Menu Category Column
df = df.set_index('Menu Category')

lst = []
for index, x in df['Sales Quantity'].iteritems():
    if index == 'Appetizers':
        x = x/sum(x)
        lst.append(x)
    elif index == 'Mains':
        x = x/sum(x)
        lst.append(x)
    elif index == 'Desserts':
        x =x/sum(x)
        lst.append(x)
lst
```

[image]

I know I need to somehow set a condition for each `Menu Category` that if `index == 'a certain menu category value'` then divide quantity by the sum of that menu category. Thus far I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would like to compliment you on using comprehensive row by row. I still use them for time to time, because I consider loops to be easier for someone else to read and understand what the principle is without running the code itself.

But ye. For this solution, I have created a couple one liners and let me explain what each are.

```
df['% Quantity of Menu'] = ((df['Sales Quantity']/df['Sales Quantity'].sum())*100).round(2)
```

For your first problem, instead of looping row to row, this divides the column value with a scalar value (which is the total of the column `df['Sales Quantity'].sum()`), then the ratio is multiplied with 100 for percentage, then round off at 2 decimal points.

```
df['%Qty of Menu Category'] = ((df['Sales Quantity']/df.groupby(['Menu Category'])['Sales Quantity'].transform('sum'))*100).round(2)
```

So, for the second problem, we need to divide the column value with the total *of each corresponding category* instead of the whole column. So, we get the value with groupby for each category `df.groupby(['Menu Category'])['Sales Quantity'].transform('sum')`, then did the same as the first one, by replacing the portion of the code.
Here, why do we use `df.groupby(['Menu Category'])['Sales Quantity'].transform('sum')` instead of `df.groupby(['Menu Category'])['Sales Quantity'].sum()`? Because for division of a series can be done either with a scalar or with a series *of same dimension*, and the former way gives us the series of same dimension.

```
df['Sales Quantity']
0    100
1     50
2     40
3    200
4    400
5    250
6    100
7    120
8     50
Name: Sales Quantity, dtype: int64

df.groupby(['Menu Category'])['Sales Quantity'].transform('sum')
0    190
1    190
2    190
3    850
4    850
5    850
6    270
7    270
8    270
Name: Sales Quantity, dtype: int64

df.groupby(['Menu Category'])['Sales Quantity'].sum()
Menu Category
Appetizers    190
Desserts      270
Mains         850
Name: Sales Quantity, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for that thorough explanation, especially for the the second column. I was having a bit of trouble understanding how .transform('sum') was able to solve the problem, but .sum() wasn't. Now, I realize that the key is perhaps in the fact that .transform('sum') renders a series with the same dimension as df['Sale Quantity']. I believe I tried something like this but with .sum() and was getting an error message. Now I see why!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `groupby` + transform `sum` to get the "Category" sums; then divide each "Sales Quantity" by their "Category" sum. This gives us the share of each menu item in their menu category.

You can also use the vectorized `div` method instead of loop for the first column:

```
df['%Qty of Menu'] = df['Sales Quantity'].div(df['Sales Quantity'].sum()).mul(100).round(2)
df['%Qty of Menu Cat'] = df.groupby('Menu Category')['Sales Quantity'].transform('sum').rdiv(df['Sales Quantity']).mul(100).round(2)
```

Output:

```
  Menu Category  Menu Item  Sales Quantity  %Qty of Menu  %Qty of Menu Cat
0    Appetizers      Fries             100          7.63             52.63
1    Appetizers    Poppers              50          3.82             26.32
2    Appetizers      Wings              40          3.05             21.05
3         Mains      Pasta             200         15.27             23.53
4         Mains     Burger             400         30.53             47.06
5         Mains      Pizza             250         19.08             29.41
6      Desserts  Ice Cream             100          7.63             37.04
7      Desserts       Cake             120          9.16             44.44
8      Desserts      Fruit              50          3.82             18.52
```